# PHP - Split website in to files

Tags: php, html, css, navigation, highlight

I am currently developing a website in purpose of learning some more, but I just could not figure this one out and I do not know what to search for exactly, I haven't found anything.

So basically I have a navigation bar, a content box, and a footer. I'd like to divide the website in to three files. That way, I would for example only need to edit one file to edit all links in the navigation bar on ALL pages.

I can simply do this by putting:

`<?php include('navigation.php'); ?>`

Where I want it to be.
But here comes my problem: on each page that I have, my navigation bar should change its active page/tab and highlight it.

My navigation bar looks like this:
`Home | News | About | Contact`

When I click `News` and land on the news page, it should get highlighted in the navigation bar (through CSS). But how can I achieve this when I have the navigation bar in one single file? Then it would highlight it on ALL pages. This is the problem I currently have and I have no clue if this is even possible in PHP?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: With PHP alone? Yes - with the creative use of session variables.

Comment: How exactly would that look? I haven't found any examples for this. @JayBlanchard

Comment: You would store a variable in the session which indicated the location. Using that you would invoke the proper CSS for that section.

Comment: i don't see a need for sessions, cant you just detect the page tour on and match it to the menu item. nothing special about using an include

Comment: Aha! I never thought about that! Very clever! Thanks for the tip @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest method: set a global variable to say "where" you are, and have the nav menu check for that:

e.g.

index.php:

```
<?php
$PAGE = 'home';
include('navigation.php');
```

navigation.php:

```
<?php

...
if (isset($PAGE) && ($PAGE == 'home')) {
    .... output "home" link with you-are-here highlight
} else {
    ... output regular home link.
}
```

Comment: Really nice! Thank you! I have a question though: What would happen if the user has two browser tabs open, with two different links up? Will the `$PAGE` only contain the latest one visited? Or would two links be highlighted in the nav bar?

Comment: each 'tab' is just like a new user in another country

Comment: php doesn't keep running when you're not doing requests. EVERY page request in php is completely independent of each other. you'd have two different $PAGE floating around for the few split seconds that PHP is building the individual pages, and then everything in PHP is gone. the onlyw ay you'd have a conflict between two pages is if you stored the data in a session or something other external system.

Answer (score 3):

You could perhaps check what is the current URL and add active class on your menu items accordingly.

```
<?php
    $url = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);    
?>
```

and then when you generate your menu links, something like this:

```
<li class='<?php echo ($url == "about.php") ? "active" : ""?>' >About</li>
```

Something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Get the page from the `p` URL handle. Check if its allowed, otherwise go to home.

Then check if the page is currently active in the menu, if so; add class `active`.

```
<?php
// Get the page from the url, example: index.php?p=contact
$page = $_GET['p'];

// Whitelist pages for safe including
$whitelist = array('home', 'news', 'about', 'contact');

// Page not found in whitelist
if (!in_array($page, $whitelist)):
    $page = 'home';
endif;

include('header.php');
include('navigation.php');
include($page . '.php'); // Include page according to url
include('footer.php');
?>


<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="index.php?p=home" class="<?php if ($page === 'home'): ?>active<?php endif; ?>">
            Home
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="index.php?p=news" class="<?php if ($page === 'news'): ?>active<?php endif; ?>">
            News
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="index.php?p=about" class="<?php if ($page === 'about'): ?>active<?php endif; ?>">
            About
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="index.php?p=contact" class="<?php if ($page === 'contact'): ?>active<?php endif; ?>">
            Contact
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```